# When does pyramid commit zodb transaction?

Tags: pyramid, zodb, autocommit

I followed the tutorial on http://docs.pylonsproject.org/docs/pyramid/en/latest/tutorials/wiki/index.html

I know that when I add or change persistent objects (in this case Page objects), the change will not be persisted until `transaction.commit()` is called. And in order to cancel changes, I can call `transaction.abort()`.

In the tutorial, however, these calls are not shown in the view callables. I assume that there is some middleware in place that will catch exceptions and call `.abort()` or call `.commit()` just before sending the HTTP response, but I don't see any mention of it anywhere in the code or config files.

Could you point me in the right direction? I just need to know what happens behind the scenes, so I know if I need to add something myself

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The [`pyramid_tm` package](http://pyramid-tm.readthedocs.org/en/latest/) is used; it installs a Tween that manages the transaction.

It simply starts a transaction for every request, and if the request was successful the transaction is committed, and aborted otherwise.

From the documentation:

> At the beginning of a request a new transaction is started using the `transaction.begin()` function. Once the request has finished all of its works (ie views have finished running), a few checks are tested:
>
> - Did some a `transaction.doom()` cause the transaction to become “doomed”? if so, `transaction.abort()`.
> - Did an exception occur in the underlying code? if so, `transaction.abort()`
>     If the `tm.commit_veto` configuration setting was used, did the commit veto callback, called with the response generated by the application, return a result that evaluates to `True`? if so, `transaction.abort()`.
>
> If none of these checks calls `transaction.abort()` then the transaction is instead committed using `transaction.commit()`.

It'll also *retry* requests (re-start them from the beginning) if there was a retryable exception (such as a ZODB commit conflict):

> When the transaction manager calls the downstream handler, if the handler raises a “retryable” exception, the transaction manager can be configured to attempt to call the downstream handler again with the same request, in effect “replaying” the request.

This behaviour is disabled by default; you can set the `tm.attempts` option to a number larger than 1 to enable it.

Comment: I can’t find the documentation for it, but if a request does not raise an exception but still returns a `4xx` response code, the transaction is aborted, correct?

Comment: @Jens: usually, a 4xx response was caused by an exception, at which point [this piece of code](https://github.com/Pylons/pyramid_tm/blob/2.x-branch/pyramid_tm/__init__.py#L144-L150) will doom the transaction. However, if a view manually created a 404 response code the pyramid_tm tween would have no way of knowing that the transaction should be aborted; call manager.doom() manually in that case.